# Can JSTL fmt:formatNumber be used to get this output: "1 234.56"?

Tags: jstl

I'm trying to get numbers formatted in this specific format:

"1 234.56"

So, two decimals, separated by a dot. And grouping thousands with a space char (optionally a single quote). The input values will never be larger than 9999.99.

I tried using patterns fo this, and even playing around with locales, but to no avail.

Comment: From my knowledge you cannot specify a pattern that prints a white space after every 3rd character. I found something similar on CodeRanch but it's not very pretty: http://www.coderanch.com/t/292958/JSP/java/fmt-formatNumber-grouping-separator. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="val" value="9999.99" /> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${val}" pattern="#,###.##" var="pat" /> 
${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")}
```

Comment: So basically string manipulation can be used in JSTL, I wasn't aware of that. I got it to work in my use case. Thanks!!

In case it helps anyone, what I did in the end is more or less like this:

    <fmt:formatNumber value="${priceData.originalValue}" groupingUsed="true" pattern="#,##0.00" var="pat" />
    <c:set var="pat" value="${fn:replace(pat, '.', '&#39;')}" /> 
    ${fn:replace(pat, ",", ".")}

I used an apostrophe as the thousands separator...

Edit: Dang, I thought code blocks in comments were possible!