# Java Spring View formatatting currency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have BigDecimal property in model. Is's storing money value .
Now i want to show money in 123 456 789,00 format.

i want to do it in view part of application. 
I am using Spring framework.

what is a best practise to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to format money value in the JSP view is to use JSTLs.

For example:

```
<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="$" type="number" maxIntegerDigits="2" value="${balance}" />
```

In your case you may have to set a different pattern (to display the space after each 3 numbers)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

Comment: i am still using <fmt:formatNumber . But i can not find pattern which i need. My pattern must look like ### ### ###.##

Comment: mmh... seems that you can't do it directly with jstl :( here is another dirty option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087544/can-jstl-fmtformatnumber-be-used-to-get-this-output-1-234-56 
or you can create your own tag

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with jsf you can use

```
<h:outputText id="balance" value="#{accountBean.balance}">
    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" groupingUsed="true"
                     maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
</h:outputText>
```

[jsfToolBox converNumber](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html)

Another example specifiying locale:

```
<h:outputText value="#{llistaV.importTotal}"rendered="#{llistaV.importTotal != null}">
 <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" locale="es-ES"/>
    <!-- pattern="###,###.###$" -->
</h:outputText>
```