# JSTL function : ${fn:replace()} Not only replaces with new pattern also adds the original value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

For example I want to replace `,` from value `A,B. .C` with a `blank`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="pat" value="A,B.  .C" /> 
        <c:out value="${pat}"/></br >
            ${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")}
        <c:out value="${pat}"/></br >
    </body>
</html>
```

expected output :

```
A,B. .C
A B. .C
```

Real output :

```
A,B. .C
A B. .C A,B. .C
```

Browser Picture

[image]

After the replaced value contains the variable `${pat}` also the original value.

What do I wrong ? Never see this before.
with these results, the function is useless.

(tested with jdk1.6.0_45 and jdk1.7.0_51 Java EE Version : Java EE 6 Web)

EDIT

from answer @rickz

I tested with

```
<c:set var="pat" value="A,B.  .C" /> 
   <c:out value="${pat}" /></br >
   ------------------------------</br >
   ${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")}</br >
   ------------------------------</br >    
   <c:out value="${pat}" /></br >
   ------------------------------</br >
```

And the output :

```
A,B. .C
------------------------------
A B. .C
------------------------------
A,B. .C
------------------------------
```

We can see the value of ${pat} is not changed
Most of the manuals on the web did not count on that ( or not explain).

[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103149/1322642)
[What is the simplest way to replace quote characters with \" sequence inside string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898166/1322642)

and many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it this way.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var="pat" value="A,B.  .C" /> 
    ${pat}</br >
    ${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")} produces an output.

Comment: You only left out the second `${pat}</br >` . But your answer point me into the right direction thanks :-)